# Facebook SDK FBLoginView getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-login

I'm following the HelloFacebookSample project bundled with the Facebook SDK 3.5. I've virtually copied and pasted everything into my own app, even the stuff from the AppDelegate, yet for some reason clicking the Login button freezes my app. Just for the record, everything authenticates correctly when connecting to the integrated framework in iOS 6, which is done through the FB SDK anyway. It's only when I try to log in using the web, i.e. hit the FBLoginView website opens, get authenticated, return to app. Here is the code in the samepl project, and I'll compare it to mine:

```
FBLoginView *loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];

loginview.frame = CGRectOffset(loginview.frame, 5, 5);
loginview.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:loginview];

[loginview sizeToFit];
```

Mine is a little different:

```
loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
loginview.delegate = self;

[self.facebookCell addSubview:loginview];

[loginview sizeToFit];
```

As for the delegate methods, I've implemented them all verbatim. Why does the app crash? There is no valid reason for a crash when all the code is pretty much identical between my app and the sample app. The debugger doesn't help much even with Zombie Objects on. The actual error is: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=somethingoranother)` Anyone got any ideas as to why this is happening?

Regards, 
Mike

**UPDATE:** It appears that the crash happens because something is recurring infinitely on a loop. Seems like over 100,000 processes were put on the main thread by the FB SDK! How?!

**UPDATE 2:** I'm beginning to think the error is here, even though I copied this straight from the sample AppDelegate.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation {
// attempt to extract a token from the url
return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
              sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                fallbackHandler:^(FBAppCall *call) {
                    NSLog(@"In fallback handler");
                }];
}
```

Does this help at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having whats seems to be the exact problem, but I have my application sandbox mode already disabled. This app has been working perfectly before, but I just upgraded the SDK and now this happens.

If I have a facebook account configured in iOs, it will work ok, but if not, It will crash.
One thing worth mentioning is if I remove the url scheme, so the app can't go to the web browser or the facebook app, It will user a web view to log in and this works too

EDIT: As far as I'm able to tell, my problem relies in not having access to my application settings in facebook.
The facebook SDK does an [FBUtility fetchAppSettings:callback:] call, more specifically, it does an

```
https://graph.facebook.com/267496536695242?fields=supports_attribution,supports_implicit_sdk_logging,suppress_native_ios_gdp,name,
```

which in the case of my app fails with:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

In comparision, any of the examples apps, for example this one, SessionLoginSample

```
https://graph.facebook.com/380615018626574?fields=supports_attribution,supports_implicit_sdk_logging,suppress_native_ios_gdp,name
```

returns correctly this:

```
{
   "supports_attribution": true,
   "supports_implicit_sdk_logging": true,
   "suppress_native_ios_gdp": 0,
   "name": "SessionLoginSample",
   "id": "380615018626574"
}
```

Because the SDK expects something it keeps making the same request and gets stuck in a loop until the simulator crashes.

To confirm this, I've manually inserted the expected parameters in the callback, modifyng the facebook sdk, and now everything work perfectly.

It's worth mentioning that I upgraded the SDK from 2.0 which was deprecated, and there was a few parameters in the settings page that were outdated (no client token set, authorization as native/Desktop instead Web, without having the app secret key in the app) but I've already set them alright..

EDIT 2:
This is the method from Facebook SDK (in FBUtility.m) that I've modified. I only added the "bad stuff" if clause.

```
+ (void)fetchAppSettings:(NSString *)appID
            callback:(void (^)(FBFetchedAppSettings *, NSError *))callback {

if (!g_fetchedAppSettingsError && !g_fetchedAppSettings) {

    NSString *pingPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?fields=supports_attribution,supports_implicit_sdk_logging,suppress_native_ios_gdp,name", appID, nil];
    FBRequest *pingRequest = [[[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:nil graphPath:pingPath] autorelease];
    if ([pingRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

        // Bad stuff
        if (error) {
            error = nil;
            result = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"true", @"supports_attribution",
                                                                @"true", @"supports_implicit_sdk_logging",
                                                                @"0", @"suppress_native_ios_gdp",
                                                                @"Your_App_Display_Name", @"name",  nil];
        }

        if (error) {
            g_fetchedAppSettingsError = error;
            [g_fetchedAppSettingsError retain];
        } else {

            g_fetchedAppSettings = [[[FBFetchedAppSettings alloc] init] retain];

            if ([result respondsToSelector:@selector(objectForKey:)]) {

                g_fetchedAppSettings.serverAppName = [result objectForKey:@"name"];
                g_fetchedAppSettings.supportsAttribution = [[result objectForKey:@"supports_attribution"] boolValue];
                g_fetchedAppSettings.supportsImplicitSdkLogging = [[result objectForKey:@"supports_implicit_sdk_logging"] boolValue];
                g_fetchedAppSettings.suppressNativeGdp = [[result objectForKey:@"suppress_native_ios_gdp"] boolValue];
            }
        }
        [FBUtility callTheFetchAppSettingsCallback:callback];
    }
         ]
        );
} else {
    [FBUtility callTheFetchAppSettingsCallback:callback];
}
```

}

Comment: Interesting, where is the URL scheme you're talking about? It'll be interesting to see how it authorises in a web view. I guess you lose the Facebook App authorisation though.

Comment: As for help with your problem. Try comparing your code to the HelloFacebookSample, then report back.

Comment: Hi, there's nothing wrong with my code. After MUCH debugging, I've reached the conclusion that the problem relies in not having access to my application. I'll edit my post providing all the information I've found.

Comment: I'm having another problem similar to yours, whereby if the app can not connect to the internet, it will crash in exactly the same way. Something wrong with the error handling? That's 3 similar crashes for 3 different reasons!

Comment: Right, great work! Could you explain in a little more detail how you got your workaround? Also, do you have any ideas as to why FBUtility can't get our app settings from Facebook?

Comment: I have no clue. I mean, I believe it has something to do with authorization permissions in the settings page of the app, but I've checked everything and still no luck. I'll add more info for my work around.

Comment: This may sound dumb but how did you modify .m files in this SDK?

Comment: That's a little more complicated to explain through here but I use cocoapods to manage libraries. I just cloned the git repo for the sdk https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk and loaded it locally via cocoapods.

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking into cocoapods as it seems like a great tool.

Answer (score 1):

Someone found the answer on another thread. In the Facebook Developer centre, the app was set to Sandboxing mode which is what caused this error. Seems it wasn't a problem with the code after all.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has fixed a server error that was causing this for a lot of developers. However, the server fix only makes the infinite loop problem less likely to happen. It is still there. I created a new bug to track the infinite loop problem.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/446010282155033

Answer (score 1):

It's a memory access error, because the loginView is in a __block space.

Just move your controller ( the loginView delegate ) in this zone and it should work.

```
FBLoginView *loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
static id staticDelegateInstance = self;

loginview.frame = CGRectOffset(loginview.frame, 5, 5);
loginview.delegate = staticDelegateInstance;

[self.view addSubview:loginview];

[loginview sizeToFit];
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on this solution? Its not clear.

Comment: Hi @Hooman, I crawled in the facebook code, I saw that the loginview is declared in a __block memory space. Which corresponds to a static memory allocation.

Declaring the Loginview delegate static avoids the memory access error.

It was two months ago, so I'd have to go and inspect my code again if you want more detail. At least, this worked perfectly for me.