# Facebook SDK FBSession infinite loop and crash

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-login

I originally used FBLoginView to start the login process in the latest Facebook SDK (3.5). However, that would crash the app because of a loop of some sort. I then read that I should try logging in using the code below as a test:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"read_stream", nil] allowLoginUI:YES
                          completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                              FBSessionState status,
                                              NSError *error) {
                              // session might now be open.
                              NSLog(@"Error - %@", error);
                          }];
```

I got exactly the same issue. A huge number of processes (with the same name) get called and the app crashes. Does anyone know why this would happen when using the Facebook SDK? Here is an image of the thread that crashes:
[image: Crash]

As you can see there's something not right here. Anyone got any ideas?

Regards,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, and tried setting sandboxing (in fb app dashboard) to false, and then it worked...

Comment: You are a hero. This has been bugging me for the past 2 days and I had no idea what it was... Thank you so much!

Comment: Sandboxing does have an impact on this -- but does completely address the problem. There was a bug on the server, and we believe we have addressed it.

Answer (score 5):

This was a bug and is now fixed.

Edited --
This has been fixed on both client and server as of the Facebook SDK 3.5.1 for iOS. Here is the link:
https://developers.facebook.com/resources/facebook-ios-sdk-3.5.1.pkg

--

Thanks for notifying us of this problem!

Comment: But we still get the problem in some cases, like when you try to log in when the device is in Aeroplane mode.

Comment: Hi @Mackey18, thanks for the quick response! We are working on a fix to the network-connectivity variant of this problem. Thanks!

Comment: @JasonClark, good to know that you guys are on the network connection variant, which seems like it is really any kind of server error.

I created a new bug to track the remaining infinite loop problem. 

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/446010282155033

Given that losing network connection could cause my app to crash, I will have to wait for the next rev after SDK 3.5. Glad to hear that you guys are on top of it.

Comment: @Mackey18, Skotch -- please try this update. Thanks!
https://developers.facebook.com/resources/facebook-ios-sdk-3.5.1.pkg

Answer (score 0):

I'm having what seems to be the exact same problem, and nearly the same stacktrace,but I already have sandboxing disable, in fact, my app has been in production for 9 months, but we were using still sdk 2.0 and just gotten around to upgrade it.

I have narrowed It down a lot. Here I give a good explanation about my problem, and a temporary solution that fixes my problem, but It's viable for production..
[Facebook SDK FBLoginView getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113756/facebook-sdk-fbloginview-getting-exc-bad-access/16148653#16148653)

[image]