# Facebook SDK 3.5 can't log in, crashes app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-login

I'm using the code from HelloFacebookSample and for some reason FBLoginView crashes my app whenever it's clicked. I've copied most of the code verbatim, so I can't see why it's crashing. Does anyone have any experience with the Facebook SDK and can help me out? I will post code if needed.

Regards,

 Mike

**UPDATE:** Here is a screenshot of my error.
[image]

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072135/how-to-track-down-cause-of-sigabrt/8072273#8072273 and post here where exactly does the crash occur

Comment: @Eugene I don't get a SIGABRT error, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS, I'll post a screenshot on the main question.

Comment: Is the HelloFacebookSample working for you? Also could you provide more detail: What version of iOS you're running on, if this fails on the device/simulator. Some code would also help debug this some more.

Comment: @CAbernathy Hi thanks for the reply. Someone posted on another thread explaining why this happens. On the Facebook dashboard my app was set to SandBoxing mode and that's why it crashed. Seems absolutely ridiculous, but everything is working now.

Comment: @Mackey18 Do you have a link to this "other thread"? Would like to see the discussion on that topic

Comment: @Kasihasi Yea sure, but there wasn't much discussion to be honest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131398/facebook-sdk-fbsession-infinite-loop-and-crash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks for bringing this to our attention.

We found a bug on the server and believe we have addressed it. Please let us know if you continue to find cases which fail in this way.

Comment: The problem here is that the Facebook iOS SDK 3.5 gets into an infinite loop when there is a server failure. If there was a server side change that reduces failures that is good, but I cannot use 3.5 as it is because anytime there is a server side failure it is going to crash the app. I'll wait until this infinite loop is fixed.

Comment: I created a new bug to track the infinite loop problem. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/446010282155033

The server fix only makes the infinite loop problem less likely to happen. It is still there.

Comment: This has been fixed on both client and server as of the Facebook SDK 3.5.1 for iOS. Here is the link: https://developers.facebook.com/resources/facebook-ios-sdk-3.5.1.pkg

Answer (score 2):

Someone found the answer on another thread. In the Facebook Developer centre, the app was set to Sandboxing mode which is what caused this error. Seems it wasn't a problem with the code after all.

Comment: Sandboxing mode does impact this, but is not the ultimate solution. See C Abernathy's answer for details

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue, just set sandboxing (in facebook -> managed app->In yourapp) to false, and then it will work...